# mod_rewrite - need help with friendly URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

How would you mod_rewrite a url to go from

directory.php?id=4
to 
directory/category/city/name/4/

I took a stab in the dark with

```
RewriteRule ^directory/*/*/*/([^/\.]+)/?$ directory.php?&id=$4
```

But not working obviously. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
RewriteRule ^directory\.php/.*/.*/.*/(.*)/$ directory.php?id=$1
```

The parentheses do the capture, and since you are only doing one capture, then the can use '$1' in the target.

Edit: I'm assuming that you want the URL without the query string to redirect to the one with the query string (not 100% clear in your question, sounds like it is the other way around)

Comment: You'll want to remove the `\.php` in the regex to allow URLs of the form `/directory/category/...` instead of `/directory.php/category/...`.

Comment: i want directory/foo/bar/foobar/4 to re-write to directory.php?id=4 .. still can't get it to work with your suggestions.

Comment: JAYKAY - it works with
^directory/.*/.*/.*/(.*)/$ directory.php?id=$1
Thank you very much!